# Multiple mongoDB related to same django rest framework project

Tags: restframeworkmongoengine

We are having one django rest framework (DRF) project which should have multiple databases (mongoDB).Each databases should be independed. We are able to connect to one database, but when we are going to another DB for writing connection is happening but data is storing in DB which is first connected.
We changed default DB and everything but no changes.

(Note : Solution should be apt for the usage of serializer. Because we need to use DynamicDocumentSerializer in DRF-mongoengine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you want to achieve. Do you want 2 mongodb databases? Write-only and read-only?

Comment: Actually we want to store the details of some projects in different DBs (mongo).Each project should have one independed DB for storing it's details. Each DB should be readable and writable. (I am very new in mongo concepts).

Comment: We are using django in server side.So for django-mongo interaction we are using mongoengine module. It is having one connect() method for connecting to DB. By using this method we are able to connect also. But problem is always data is going to the first connected DB while running the django server. If we are trying to connect to another DB, the method is returning success but data is going to DB connected at first time.

Comment: Did you try: http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.context_managers.switch_db?

Comment: Yeah, I read about this one. But this is for short term switching, right ?

Comment: In our case we have urls for each project(DB wise). Suppose localhost:8000/api/v2/post_data/project1/ should write data into "project1" DB(mongo).Similarly localhost:8000/api/v2/post_data/project2/ should connect to project2 DB and write the data.As mentioned above for reading also urls will be there.How to implement this?

Answer (score 0):

While running `connect()` just assign an [alias](http://docs.mongoengine.org/apireference.html#mongoengine.register_connection) for each of your databases and then for each Document specify a [db_alias](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/connecting.html#multiple-databases) parameter in `meta` that points to a specific database alias:

`settings.py`:

```
from mongoengine import connect


connect(
    alias='user-db',
    db='test',
    username='user',
    password='12345',
    host='mongodb://admin:qwerty@localhost/production'
)

connect(
    alias='book-db'
    db='test',
    username='user',
    password='12345',
    host='mongodb://admin:qwerty@localhost/production'
)
```

`models.py`:

```
from mongoengine import Document


class User(Document):
    name = StringField()

    meta = {'db_alias': 'user-db'}

class Book(Document):
    name = StringField()

    meta = {'db_alias': 'book-db'}
```

Comment: But here the document will go to a particular database always, right ?[User document will go to user-db and Book document will go to book-db(aliases)]. In our case by changing the urls(database specific) same documents need to go to corresponding database.

Comment: For example, we are having two documents User and Book. If the url is host:port/main/project1/(one db is there with name project1) all documents (User and Book) should go to project1 DB.Similarly if url is host:port/main/project2/ these documents (including User and Book) should go to project2 DB. So according to urls we need connect and disconnect the DBs(switch the DB).

Comment: Did you understand what is our need? Is this possible in mongoengine?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, I finally get what you need.

What you could do is write a really simple middleware that maps your url schema to the database:

```
from mongoengine import *


class DBSwitchMiddleware:
   """
   This middleware is supposed to switch the database depending on request URL.
   """
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        # list all the mongoengine Documents in your project
        import models
        self.documents = [item for in dir(models) if isinstance(item, Document)]

    def __call__(self, request):
        # depending on the URL, switch documents to appropriate database
        if request.path.startswith('/main/project1'):
             for document in self.documents:
                 document.cls._meta['db_alias'] = 'db1'
        elif request.path.startswith('/main/project2'):
             for document in self.documents:
                 document.cls._meta['db_alias'] = 'db2'

        # delegate handling the rest of response to your views
        response = get_response(request)

        return response
```

Note that this solution might be prone to race conditions. We're modifying a Documents globally here, so if one request was started and then in the middle of its execution a second request is handled by the same python interpreter, it will overwrite `document.cls._meta['db_alias']` setting and first request will start writing to the same database, which will break your database horribly.

Same python interpreter is used by 2 request handlers, if you're using multithreading. So with this solution you can't start your server with multiple threads, only with multiple processes.

To address the threading issues, you can use [threading.local()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). If you prefer context manager approach, there's also a [contextvars](https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html) module.

Comment: Actually I also expect the same issue which you have mentioned above.In our case more than one request may be hit at the server simultaneously time because multiple persons are depending the same server from different client (desktop application from each persons laptop).

Comment: So now we are planning to run different server (same host but different port) for each project.So in urls port number will change, right ? Then default connection will be made to the DB represented in url and data will go to that DB. Did you get what I am trying to say?

Comment: Eg : host:8000/main/project1/ - default connection will be made with project1 DB and whole data will be added to this DB. Similarly for second DB(project2) url will be like host:8001/main/project2/

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. First, domains would be considered different (if the ports are different, the domains are different and CORS would prohibit that). Checking the host:port will take even more effort: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.get_host.

Comment: And a couple more general suggestions. I'd advice against using django with mongoengine for most production cases. I mean, mongo is good if you need to store and validate deeply nested configuration jsons, but if you need to store any real-life data (even a blog with posts and users), you'd be better off with SQL. You can also take a look into djongo project, which is meant to convert Django ORM functions into MongoDB queries: https://github.com/nesdis/djongo.

Comment: @NidhinSachi By the way, to handle the multithreading issues, you can use threading.local (https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html). If you prefer context manager approach, there's also contextvars module (https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextvars.html).

Comment: I read about djongo DB connector also. But using these things not able to get the requirements.We need DynamicDocumentSerializer which is not availble in djongo.And in this one also I faced issue same as in DRFME.

Comment: Sorry. Can you explain what did you mean by "Checking the host:port will take even more effort" ? Anyway I will explain what I have meant.We are not checking the port number in our logic. If one person is dealing with one project(or DB) from his laptop he need to give the port number(in the GUI of desktop application) in which the dedicated server is running.

Comment: So all persons working with one project will give that port number(say 8000) in url and others working in another project will give it's port number(8001). Both will be independed.Did you get ?

Comment: @NidhinSachi By more effort I meant that if you want to know the hostname of your machine, in django this is often done via sites framework (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/sites/), which I find cumbersome to maintain.

Comment: How can I contact you for further support ?

Comment: @NidhinSachi Nidhin, I think I'm well over my time budget for a single question that didn't really require any DRF-Mongoengine specific skills - just googling the documentation. I'm sorry, I can't spend much more time answering questions.